# Problem transformation json file to array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, file-get-contents, fwrite

This is Data recovery from $_POST

```
$list = 
array(0=>$_POST['matricule'],1=>$_POST['nom'],2=>$_POST['prenom'],3=>$_POST['dn'],4=>$_POST['tel'],5=>$_POST['mail'],6=>$_POST['sexe'],7=>$_POST['adresse']);                       
$contenu_json = json_encode($list);
fwrite($fp, $contenu_json); // "test.json"
```

And this Example result in test.json :

```
 ["123","test","test","test","test","test","test","test"]["2","test","test","test","","","",""]
```

Sample code 2:

```
$json_source = file_get_contents("test.json");
$data = json_decode($json_source, true);
echo '$data[1]';
```

Output $data[0] is "" :( . i want to see "123"

```
My objectif is to see all data json in form like :
    <input name="id" type="text" value="<?= $data[0] ?>" >
```

what's the problem?

Comment: What is shown is not valid json. Paste what's in the file into a json validator to confirm

Comment: I need to read all data in the json file,but when i did  '$date[0]'; i see nothing

Comment: Did you validate your file as mentioned?

Comment: i don't understand you, 
my objectif is to see all data json in form like :
    <input name="id" type="text" value="<?= $data[0] ?>" >

but $date[0] i see nothing , i would see "123" for example

Comment: Follow the first comment I made.

Comment: i understand, so how to make it valid?

it generated automatique 

`$list = 
array(0=>$_POST['matricule'],1=>$_POST['nom'],2=>$_POST['prenom'],3=>$_POST['dn'],4=>$_POST['tel']);                    
$contenu_json = json_encode($list); 
fwrite($fp, $contenu_json); `

Comment: You need an outer array for all the inner arrays produced by that code. `[][]` is not a valid structure but `[[],[]]` is

Comment: ah thank you i understand, so you have a solution how to change this code?  to be  [[],[]] and not [][] when i execute it two times :) :

`$list = array(0=>$_POST['matricule'],1=>$_POST['nom'] ...);

$contenu_json = json_encode($list);

 fwrite($fp, $contenu_json); `

Comment: Set file up to contain one empty json array. Read whole file and decode it. Push new sub array and encode whole master array to print whole file. Using database would be simpler also

Comment: Thank you :D @charlietfl